# Implicitly declare all variables volatile

Tags: c, gcc, volatile

Does gcc have an option to disable read/write optimizations for global variables not explicitly defined as volatile?

My team is running out of program memory in our embedded C project, built using gcc. When I enable optimizations to reduce code size, the code no longer works as expected because we have not been using the volatile keyword where we ought to have been. That is, I was able to resolve the presenting problem by declaring a few variables accessed in ISRs volatile. However, I don't have any level of certainty that those are the *only* variables I need to declare volatile and I just haven't noticed the other bugs yet.

I have heard that "some compilers" have a flag to implicitly declare everything volatile, but that I should resist the temptation because it is a "substitute for thought" (see https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword).

Yes, but thought is expensive. Feel free to try to talk me out of it in the comments section, but I'm hoping for a quick fix to get the code size down without breaking the application.

Comment: So you are running out of memory, and want to prevent the optimizer from working as it should? Doesn't sound making any sense at all. Write the code properly!

Comment: Dude, I'm assuming gcc has more than one code size optimization up its sleeve. "Write the code properly" is good advice for future development, but I need a solution for the code I already have. Maybe we'll have to review and rewrite the entire code base (and the 100+ variants of our application that we've released over the years) as you suggest, but if there's a cheaper alternative, then I'm all ears.

Comment: Do you realize that what we are talking about here is *undefined behavior*?

Comment: Fixing your code so to be semantically correct is the solution that makes the most business sense in the medium term and longer, unless the product is scheduled for discontinuation.  Until you do so, you are likely to continue to experience new and interesting problems, and you will need to worry that your software gets out the door with (more) bugs.

Comment: Anyway, if making the compiler treat all file-scope variables as if they were volatile actually produces correct behavior, then why not make them all *actually* `volatile`?  That's a minimal-thought exercise that you can walk back from over time as you have the opportunity for review.

Comment: @EugeneSh, I'm not sure I know what you mean by undefined behavior. Up to this point, my team has assumed that the compiler understands that a variable might get changed by another thread or ISR at any moment (i.e. what we now understand as volatile treatment by gcc). What I am considering is the option of forcing gcc to agree with our original understanding. Seems pretty well defined to me?

Comment: @IsaacSutherland The code as is currently is exhibiting an undefined behavior, which is manifesting by the fact it is behaving differently under different compilation options. How can you tell only the `volatile/non-volatile` thing is causing it? There might be other bugs showing up only with optimizations enabled. Such a strict aliasing violation and others. I was in a similar situation some time before I've registered on SO, so unfortunately I've left broken code behind (and gave up on optimizations) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do it by for example redefining all basic types as the same but with volatile specifier. Anyway if all variables in your code will be volatile I expect that size of your application will be larger than before optimizations.

**My solution is**: enable optimizations for part of the code. If your application got some functional architecture you can start enabling optimizations and test if this functionality works properly. It's much easier than optimize everything and analyze why nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something besides `-O0`?

I expect that it's not too difficult to hack GCC for a quick experiment.  This place in `grokdeclarator` in `gcc/c/c-decl.c` is probably a good place to unconditionally inject a `volatile` qualifier for the interesting `storage_class` values (probably `csc_none`, `csc_extern`, `csc_static` in your case).

```
/* It's a variable.  */
/* An uninitialized decl with `extern' is a reference.  */
int extern_ref = !initialized && storage_class == csc_extern;

type = c_build_qualified_type (type, type_quals, orig_qual_type,
                   orig_qual_indirect);
```

The experiment should tell you whether this is feasible from a performance/code size point of view and if it is, you might want to submit this as a proper upstream patch.

Comment: Cool. But maintaining a special version of a compiler along with a project? I would say "no, thank you...". And introducing potential bugs in compiler just to work around the project bugs.. Definitely no, thank you. Though I am not the OP..